How do I determine whether a ZoneInfo is an alias?
I am having trouble identifying whether a ZoneInfo is built with an alias:
> a = ZoneInfo('Atlantic/Faeroe')
> b = ZoneInfo('Atlantic/Faroe')
> a == b
False

It seems like these ZoneInfos are identical in practice. How do I identify that they are the same, as opposed to e.g. EST and UTC which are different?

somewhat related read which might be interesting, also talks about all the linked timezones: Australia/Lord_Howe is the weirdest timezone

The tzdata package publishes the data for the IANA time zone database.
If installed, one could compare the data files for those zones located in:
<PYTHON_DIR>\Lib\site-packages\tzdata\zoneinfo\Atlantic

The data files for Faeroe and Faroe compare as binary same.
Programmatically, the binary data can be directly read and compared:
from importlib import resources

with resources.open_binary('tzdata.zoneinfo.Atlantic', 'Faroe') as f:
    data1 = f.read()
with resources.open_binary('tzdata.zoneinfo.Atlantic', 'Faeroe') as f:
    data2 = f.read()

print(data1 == data2)  # True

Ref: https://tzdata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#examples
There is also the file <PYTHON_DIR>\Lib\site-packages\tzdata\zoneinfo\tzdata.zi which is a text representation of the IANA database, and contains the line:
L Atlantic/Faroe Atlantic/Faeroe

An L line means Link LINK_FROM LINK_TO to define an alias.  This indicates that Atlantic/Faeroe is an alias for the Atlantic/Faroe time zone defined earlier in the file.

Use BaseUtcOffset of the zone to see if they have the same offset.
This does not mean they are "the same" always, but it means they are the same right now. Daylight Saving Time may change that comparison at other times.
That is a partial solution.  It does not mean they are aliases of each other.
